# I have a document center in 2010. Can I set unique doc IDs by library?

Tags: document-library

So if I have an HR, accountant, admin library I and start them with HR ACT ADM

Can it be assigned by folder?

Answer (score 0):

Document Id is a Site Collection feature. By default you can only specify a "seed" to have all Ids to begin with.

You would need to build your own Document Id provider (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521589(v=office.14).aspx) if you need special rules.